# Braintree Paypal authorization doesn't work on iOS >9

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal, authorization, braintree

I integrated Braintree SDK into my iOS app project using Cocoa Pods. Version of the Braintree SDK installed is 4.1.3. I followed guide on Braintree web site (https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/overview/ios/v4) to set up custom button that will start the process of paypal user authorization. After implementing everything as suggested in the web giude, I tested paypal authorization with sandbox environment on device with iOS 8.4 installed. Everything works flawlessly, but when I tried my app on device with iOS 9.2 installed I couldn't authorize with paypal. I set some breakpoints in project and discovered that this method, which is implemented in BTAppSwitch.m file, always returns NO:

```
- (BOOL)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication {
    for (Class<BTAppSwitchHandler> handlerClass in self.appSwitchHandlers) {
        if ([handlerClass canHandleAppSwitchReturnURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication]) {
            [handlerClass handleAppSwitchReturnURL:url];
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Value of the url at the moment when this method is called is similar to this one: com.myapp.payments://onetouch/v1/success?ba_token=BA-HERMES-SANDBOX-TOKEN

Did someone experience similar problem and how did you overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

I work at Braintree.

There are a few steps required to make sure the browser switch works on iOS9.

1) Make sure you've added the required schemes: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/ios/v4#paypal-and-venmo-url-schemes

2) Ensure that the delegate protocols are setup correctly to present SFSafariViewController: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/client-side/ios/v4#implementing-delegate-protocols

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but it not solving problem because problem is that ([handlerClass canHandleAppSwitchReturnURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication]) checking does not allow to execute code inside itself and when i press "checkout" button nothing happens

Comment: nothing happens I mean - (BOOL)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication returns NO

Comment: Diagnosing this issue will be very specific to your integration. Please reach out to our [support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) for further assistance.